# Use Gmail draft as HTML Template

Tags: html, google-apps-script, gmail

I'm trying to use the HTML body from a Gmail draft and then use the HTML Template Class to replace certain pieces of text.

I can Get the HTML body from the draft and Create and send a new email from that draft

```
function myFunction() {
  //Get the Draft as html
  var draft = GmailApp.search('subject:Test Email label:draft', 0, 1);
  var html = draft[0].getMessages()[0].getBody()

  //Set the template file as a variable
  var body = HtmlService.createTemplate(html);

  body.first = 'Tester';

  //evaluate the html, make substitutions, and get the html body for the email
  var email_html = body.getCode();
  Logger.log(email_html)

  //Send the email(s)
  MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: 'test@gmail.com',
  subject: 'Sample Email from Draft',
  htmlBody: email_html,
  });
}
```

The Problem:
In the logs, the variable in the HTML to be replaced shows as **<?= myVar?&gt**.

When I use the evaluate() method, the replacement doesn't take place.

Does anyone have an idea of how to read in the HTML body from a Gmail draft and use it as a template?

Comment: You'll need to fight the escaping applied by Gmail and Google internally to the message body. So you must replace escaped characters with the raw characters.

Comment: Thanks! That worked!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by using the .replace() method instead of .evaluate().getContent().

I tried to replace the escaped characters in the HTML retrieved from the draft email, but when I ran the evaluate method it threw errors about a missing ; in the code. I banged my head against the wall for a bit and then decided to take a different approach.

The following code achieves the goal and uses the header row values as the merge field identifiers in the draft email.

I'm sure there is a faster way to set the regular expressions and complete the replacements, but this works and the runtime doesn't seem to be an issue.

If anyone has a cleaner way to remove the repetitious elements in the code, please let me know!

Here is a link to copy the Google Sheet with the embedded script. [Email from Draft Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iXm7sBcTJ6RWuw7FEmvvUFuYJMobRHoj_uIQHr9bq2E/copy)

The goal was to give an end user the ability to merge from the sheet into an email without using an add-on that was limited to 50 emails before being asked to purchase. This is limited only by Gmail Quotas.

```
function EmailFromDraft() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var temp = []

  //get the header row values
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  //get the values for all other rows in the sheet
  data = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  //Set the replacement variables from the header row, wrap them in braces to match the draft email and put into array
  for (var i in headers) {
    var row = headers[i];
    for (var i in row) {
      var item = '{' + row[i] + '}';
      temp.push(item);
    }
  }

  //Get the Draft as html

  //Prompt user for Draft Subject
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.prompt('Template Choice', 'Please enter the Subject of your Email Template. (Must have the Drafts Label.).', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  var subject = response.getResponseText()

  //var subject = 'Drug Test Email'
  var search = 'subject:' + subject + ' label:draft'
  Logger.log(search)
  var draft = GmailApp.search(search, 0, 1);
  var html = draft[0].getMessages()[0].getBody();

  //Reg Expression Samples//
  //var re = /{first}/gi;
  //var str = '{first} are round, and {first} are juicy.';
  //var newstr = str.replace(re, 'oranges');
  //Logger.log(newstr);

  //iterate through the rows in the sheet, make replacements, send the email
  for (var i in data){
    row = data[i];
    //Format each header item as a regular expression
    var item0 = new RegExp(temp[0], 'g');
    var item1 = new RegExp(temp[1], 'g');
    var item2 = new RegExp(temp[2], 'g');
    var item3 = new RegExp(temp[3], 'g');
    var item4 = new RegExp(temp[4], 'g');
    var item5 = new RegExp(temp[5], 'g');
    var item6 = new RegExp(temp[6], 'g');
    var item7 = new RegExp(temp[7], 'g');
    var item8 = new RegExp(temp[8], 'g');
    var item9 = new RegExp(temp[9], 'g');
    var item10 = new RegExp(temp[10], 'g');
    var item11 = new RegExp(temp[11], 'g');
    var item12 = new RegExp(temp[12], 'g');

    //Set the email address variable. This is the only inflexible column
    var email = row[0];

    //Make the replacements
    var emailHtml = html.replace(item0, row[0]).replace(item1, row[1]).replace(item2, row[2]).replace(item3, row[3]).replace(item4, row[4]).replace(item5, row[5]).replace(item6, row[6]).replace(item7, row[7]).replace(item8, row[8]).replace(item9, row[9]).replace(item10, row[10]).replace(item11, row[11]).replace(item12, row[12]);
    //var html_final = html.replace(item3, row[3]);

    //Send the email(s)
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: email,
      subject: subject,
      htmlBody: emailHtml,
    });
   }
}
```